# Why internalization is not working with JHIpster Microservices application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jhipster, spring-thymeleaf

> I developed one spring boot microservice application using jhipster
> tool and we have one quotation.html form it contains name and details
> of the product I am trying to apply langauage translations to the name
> and details labels based user language

for that i made changes in these classes

```
 @Configuration
    public class LocaleConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
        @Bean
        public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
            SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
            slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
            return slr;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
            lci.setParamName("lang");
            return lci;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        }
        
    }
```

added language messages files at this location

[image]

> i am sending user language key as request param like this

`localhost:8080/api/pord/quotation?lang=de`
based on this lang value it shoud read keys from respective messages file

> Note: The issue is it is always reading language keys from
> messages_en.properties file
>
> sample quotation.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

    <div class="page-content container-fluid">
        <div class="title">
            <h3>
                <center>
                    <th:block>
                        <span th:text="#{invoice.quotation}"></span >
                    </th:block>
                  </center>
              </h3
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `src/main/resources/templates/error.html` template it includes `th:lang="${#locale.language}"` while your template does not.

It's probably not the solution but it will help debugging by showing the value of lanaguage.